# Do some elements inherit their sibling's parameter's values if we won't specirfy the parameters and values for these elements?

Tags: css, inheritance

Something that I was wondering while styling my latest HTML5/CSS3 baby: Do some elements inherit their sibling's parameter's values if we won't specirfy the parameters and values for these elements? Basically I had a situation in which 3/4 of the website's home page elements have been styled already in stylesheet and what was left was the footer section.

Last element that I've styled was a boxcontent with two columns. The columns have been styled with a float:left parameter and value. Upon that when I've reloaded the page, the footer section which is not styled like I've mentioned before, have moved up and to the extreme right from column2 of boxcontent section.

I'm wondering why the footer section has inherited some of the sibling's section's parameters and values if the footer is not even inheriting this data straight from it's parent element - that is body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Children inherit parent's values, but siblings do not inherit each other's parameters.  Your layout was changed, because you've used floating, which can affect positioning of elements that are below the floated blocks.  When using floating for positioning it is a good idea to clear floats.

Answer (score 1):

Elements don't inherit siblings styles, but do inherit their parent's styling. I've ran into layout issues that I've traced up many levels on a parent. [Chrome's developer tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/elements) are a great way to inspect where styling is coming from for any selected element.